# Set id of cf7 in the data save function

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

My goal is to save the data sent by the cf7 module inside a table external to those created by wordpress I found this procedure:

1. Create Custom table

   CREATE TABLE candidate(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   title VARCHAR(50)
   );
2. Create contact form 7 fields

   [text* title]
   [submit "Send"]
3. Add Below code to function.php

   ```
     function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
        //set your db details
        $mydb = new wpdb('root','','cistom_db','localhost');

        $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $form_to_DB ) 
            $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
        $title = $formData['title'];

        $mydb->insert( 'candidate', array( 'title' =>$title ), array( '%s' ) );
    }
    remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
    add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
   ```

all clear and simple, however, I was wondering how to mix the specific id of the cf7 module?

```
$form_id = $contact_form->id();
if ($form_id == 2654 ) // 123 => Your Form ID.
{
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "mix" but this might be a better question asked on the [Contact Form 7 forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7/) so that it can be answered by people who are familiar with the plugin.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee pass only the id of the specific form to the code above which will have to save the data in a custom table

Comment: Questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins is [considered to be off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more. A better place to ask this type of question may be [The Official WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/) or the plugin specific support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Get current form.
$wpcf7      = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
$contact_form_id = $wpcf7->id;
```

Comment: how to specify the precise id by hand passing the number?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want specific from ID to pass by hand ( I guess you mean manually) then you can simply/directly pass the ID of your choice to the variable e.g. $form_id = 123;